# Number of Distinct Elements in Set of Products of 2 Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices

Let $X=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\frac{2\pi}{5} & -\sin\frac{2\pi}{5}\\\sin\frac{2\pi}{5} & \cos\frac{2\pi}{5}\end{pmatrix}$ and $Y=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$.

Find the number of distinct elements in the set, $Z$, which is the set of all matrices that can be generated from taking products of $X$ and $Y$ (ex. $X^3YX^4Y\in Z$).

Comment: Note that $YXY=X^{-1}$. Next, find $m, n \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $X^m=I=Y^n$. This should help you in finding the order of $Z$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that there is a minimal integer $n$ such that $X^n=I$. Furthermore, $Y^2=I$ and $XYXY=I$. Hence
$$
Z=\langle X,Y: X^n,Y^2,(XY)^2\rangle\simeq D_{2n}
$$
where $D_{2n}$ is the [dihedral group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group) of order $2n$.

Comment: Could you please explain how those two facts imply $|Z|=m\cdot n$?

Comment: Also, can an expression such as the example in the OP always be simplified into the form $X^iY^j$?